# C# Regex Atomic Opening and Closing Brackets

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have the following which is a placeholder, I'm trying to use Atomic groups to catch double opening and closing brackets in pairs:

> {{(?>{{(?)|}}(<-DEPTH>)|[^{}])*}}(?(DEPTH)(?!))
>
> I am {{name}} and I have {{scales}: red {{metallic_scales}: shiny and glistering}} scales}}

Safe to say, I'm not really having much success.

So I'd want something like:

1. {{name}}
2. {{scales}: red {{metallic_scales}: shiny and glistering}} scales}}
3. {{metallic_scales}: shiny and glistering}}

Comment: I would suggest changing your approach, using a `Stack` instead of Regex

Comment: What's a Stack?

Comment: Check that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack, I also recommend that you search for balanced brackets implementations

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd like to use Regex if possible. I'll research what you provided tho, this seems a good thing to use.

Comment: The brackets opening and closing double are to determine when a grouping really close. Because you can do {{metallic_scales}: shiny and glistering|{chromatic_scales}: words}}.

Comment: Maybe that can help you https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Comment: See the answer below with the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?=                    # Start of a positive lookahead to enable overlapping matches
  (?<results>          # The group storing the results
    {{                 # {{ (left-hand delimiter)
      (?>              # Start of an atomic group
        (?!{{|}}).|    # Any char not starting {{ or }} char sequence, or
        {{(?<DEPTH>)|  # {{ and a value pushed on to DEPTH group stack, or
        }}(?<-DEPTH>)  # }} and a value popped from the DEPTH group stack
      )*               # Zero or more repetitions of the atomic group patterns
    }}                 # }} substring
    (?(DEPTH)(?!))     # Conditional construct failing the match if DEPTH stack is not empty
  )                    # End of the results group
)                      # End of the lookahead
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%0D%0A%20%20%28%3F%3Cresults%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%3F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%3F!%7B%7B%7C%7D%7D%29.%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%28%3F%3CDEPTH%3E%29%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%28%3F%3C-DEPTH%3E%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%3F%28DEPTH%29%28%3F!%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%29%0D%0A%20%29&i=I%20am%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%20and%20I%20have%20%7B%7Bscales%7D%3A%20red%20%7B%7Bmetallic_scales%7D%3A%20shiny%20and%20glistering%7D%7D%20scales%7D%7D&o=x).

C# declaration:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"
    (?=                  # Start of a positive lookahead to enable overlapping matches
      (?<results>          # The group storing the results
        {{                 # {{ (left-hand delimiter)
          (?>              # Start of an atomic group
            (?!{{|}}).|    # Any char not starting {{ or }} char sequence, or
            {{(?<DEPTH>)|  # {{ and a value pushed on to DEPTH group stack, or
            }}(?<-DEPTH>)  # }} and a value popped from the DEPTH group stack
          )*               # Zero or more repetitions of the atomic group patterns
        }}                 # }} substring
        (?(DEPTH)(?!))     # Conditional construct failing the match if DEPTH stack is not empty
      )                    # End of the results group
    )                      # End of the lookahead", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var results = reg.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["results"].Value);
```